# UWP app where to put static xml file in app

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP app I'm working on and in that app I have an .XML file that I need to read from sometimes. I've just been hard coding the location of the file while debugging but now that I want to try to run the app on a remote device I need do actually put that file somewhere and be able to read from it.

Is there a place where this file should go where whether I'm running the project locally or on a remote device I'll have access to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually put it anywhere inside your project. It's perfectly fine. Check this out: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/read-xml-file-in-windows-10-universal-app/

But the other thing that I'd suggest to you is to save the XML file in the local storage: http://jamescroft.co.uk/blog/uwp/how-to-implement-local-storage-in-universal-windows-apps/

Hope it helps!

Comment: tried following this tutorial here but my file doesn't show up in the storage  http://amadeusw.com/iot/custom-resource-files-in-uwp-windows-10

Comment: I'd really suggest to just use this approach: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/read-xml-file-in-windows-10-universal-app/

Comment: k, trying it now.

Comment: actually both approaches worked! I put the file in my Assets folder and set the build action as Content, but when trying to read it wasn't copied to the /Appx folder, it was actually in Appx\Assets.

Comment: Glad it helped! Good luck!